# What does it mean to be "in the Elks"?

Tags: meaning

I am reading the book "Metaphors We Live By" by Lakoff and Johnson and in there, there ins an example sentence: [Harry is in the Elks](http://norvig.com/mwlb.html). Is the Elks a place?

Comment: Reminds me of the first time I walked down West Street in Annapolis, Maryland, and encountered an arrow-shaped neon sign reading "MOOSE PARKING IN REAR".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Elks* in this case is referring to the [Benevolent and Protective Order of the Elks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benevolent_and_Protective_Order_of_Elks), an American fraternal order/social club.

Comment: Oh, of course. When I read the question I was thinking it was some kind of metaphor, like "He's in the dumps"!

Comment: Sounds like the right place for Harry. [joke]